# In Rails, Convert string from date_select to Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a string like this:

```
{2=>1, 3=>1, 1=>2008}
```

It was generated from a select field like this:

```
<%= user_record.date_select :response, {
                            order: [:month, :day, :year], 
                            prompt: { 
                              day: 'Select day', 
                              month: 'Select month', 
                              year: 'Select year' 
                            }, 
                            start_year: Date.today.year - 12, 
                            end_year: Date.today.year - 110
                          } %>
```

And stored as a string in the database. *(I can't change this to a date type, because it's user generated content).*

This causes 2 problems:
I want to show a humanized version of the date on the Show view. Right now it looks like {2=>1, 3=>1, 1=>2008}

I want to show a date select input on the Edit View form field. Right now it errors with

```
undefined method `year' for "{2=>1, 3=>1, 1=>2008}":String
```

I have tried splitting the string, and stripping characters, but is there a better solution in Ruby?

Comment: Have you considered wrapping the hash in a PORO (like in the presenter and/or decorator pattern)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a customer setter and getter method to your model to translate between the incoming hash from the view and the string type database column.

Something like this might work:

```
def response
  Date.parse(super)
end

def response=(value)
  value = Date.new(value[1], value[2], value[3]) if value.is_a?(Hash)

  super(value.to_s)
end
```

Comment: I believe the getter won't work here, you'll need to convert the string saved in the database ("{2=>1, 3=>1, 1=>2008}") to a readable and parsable Date format. But this answer is what I would've done.

Comment: Of course, when there are already invalid records in the production database then they need to be clean up too. Not sure if that is the case or if the OP noticed the issue in development already.